# "come to" usage : later I come to that question, is it correct?

Tags: word-usage

The context is:

> In this answer I see people mention xxx , then I follow a link in the
>   accepted answer and **come to** another answer: xxxxx.

What's the appropriate word to use here? **turn to** another answer ?

Is **come to** correct here?

Becasue I check the dictionary and it says that **come to** only has 1 meaning, which I think it's a not a good fit literally:

> ### come to
>
> PHRASAL VERB When someone who is unconscious comes to, they become
>   conscious.
>
> > When he came to and raised his head, he saw Barney.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error in your sentence parsing, and thus in your search parameters of your dictionary query.

The verb you are looking at is not "come to" but "come", which has as one of its meanings to "arrive".

We can see this more clearly if we replace "come" with its directional inverse "go".

> ...and *go* to another answer

or, alternatively, an equivalent

> ...and *arrive* at another answer

One thing to note is that all of these synonyms were originally designed and used to describe physical movement, with the differences being mostly describing space relative to the speaker and/or listener. (Compare "here" vs "there"). Thus,

> The dog can decide to either go to you or to come to me.

Comment: So **come to** is still acceptable here?

Comment: @Rick Yes, it is acceptable to use it here. But for your greater understanding I would NOT advise you to think of the grouping as (come to) (another answer), but rather as (come)(to another answer). See [this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld), and especial definitions 1a and 2a1.

Comment: Ok I got it. Thank you